# How do I use JQuery to swap images when clicked on anchor tag and outside element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I've spent 8 hours today trying to figure this out since I am new to this but I can't come to completing this.  I would appreciate it if someone can point me in the right direction at the very least.

I have the following code:

```
<a href="#" class="image_one sprite"></a>

<a href="#" class="image_two sprite"></a>
```

CSS:

```
.sprite {
  background-image: url('sprite.png');
}
.image_one {
  background-position: -25px -85px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 13px;
}
.image_two {
  background-position: -25px -105px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 13px;
}
.image_one_active {
  background-position: -25px -35px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 13px;
}
.image_two_active {
  background-position: -25px -55px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 13px;
}
```

What I am trying to do is this:

When a user clicks on image_one the class should change to image_one_active
and when the user clicks on something else the class should go away and image_one should be re-activated.  I need the same function for image_two.

Now, when a user is on image_one_active and they click on image_two, image_one_active should revert to image_one and then image_two should become image_two_active.

I tried using the following in Jquery but I can't figure it out:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".image_one").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("image_two");

        });
    });
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".image_one").click(function () {
            $(".image_one").attr("class", "image_one sprite");
        });
    });
})(jQuery);

$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var container = $(".image_two");

    if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
        $(".image_two").attr("class", "image_one sprite");
    }
});
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can do this the right way.

Comment: For starters `$(". image_two")` is invalid. Why the space? Also there is a `$(".mage_one")` I'm assuming that's a typo.

Comment: @Lavabeams Thanks for catching it.  I made a type here but it's correct in my solution.

Comment: if i am reading this correctly you have not yet been able to get any jquery to fire successfully?  when I am having issues with jquery operating i like to start with a simple $(document).ready(function(){ alert("jQuery is active");});  try this and if you are setup properly you ought to get a popup on your page .. if not your issue lies elsewhere and we can fix the logic afterwards

Comment: If you have your CSS defined in the header and the JS files at the bottom of the document, `jQuery(function() {});` would work as well.  @AAA Try not to bind events to `.mouseup()`, use `.click()` instead.  [Also this website](http://jsfiddle.net/) is your friend if you're doing simple things have to show your work to others.

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica `.click()` is deprecated. Use the `.on('click'...` instead.

Comment: @Lavabeams Really, `.click()` is deprecated?  Personally I only use `.on('click', function(){})` in my code, but this will definitely change my advice I give to people.  Thanks for the info broski.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example that should solve most of what you are asking for, that I have tried to make very clear and readable for you to get some understanding and solve this for yourself.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', '.image_one', function(evt){
    $('image_one').addClass('image_one_active');
    $('image_two').removeClass('image_two_active');
    evt.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.image_two', function(evt){
    $('image_one').removeClass('image_one_active');
    $('image_two').addClass('image_two_active');
    evt.stopPropagation();
  });

  $(document).on('click', function(){
    $('image_one').removeClass('image_one_active');
    $('image_two').removeClass('image_two_active');
  });
});
```

I added in the `event.stopPropagation()` to stop the event firing up to the `click` event handler on `document` and causing the classes to always be removed.

Also you could make this read easier by making some changes to your css also.

```
.image_one {
  background-position: -25px -85px;
  height: 14px;
  width: 13px;
}
.image_one.image_one_active {
   background-position: -25px -35px;
 }
```

You could then also shorten down the class of `image_one_active` to just `active`, this would start to make your code more readable and understandable which is always a plus!

Comment: Thanks @lavabeams.  I will try and implement this and will report back here.  Thanks for helping.

Comment: Thanks once again.  I tried your script but it doesn't do anything.  I am not sure if I am missing something or some other problem.

Answer (score 0):

i would go about this problem in a slightly different fashion... instead of changing the class of your images entirely i would recommend just adding and removing an additional ".active" class to them

so the html element would look like

```
<a href="#" class="image_one active"/>
```

then you can change your css to read

```
.image_one.active {
     /* This selector targets only elements of the .image_one
        class that also have the .active class as well... */
}

.image_one{ /* ... */ }
```

i bring up this point because in my experience it is easier to add and remove a second class with jquery following this procedure

```
$('.image_one').removeClass('active');
$('.image_one').addClass('active');
// you also have this function available to check if an element has a class
$('.image_one').hasClass('active');
```

documentation coming soon here

jQuery:  [**.addClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) - [**.removeClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) - [**.hasClass()**](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/)

---

a few more things i should mention:

are you using this syntax intentionally?

```
(function ($) { /*...*/ })(jQuery)
```

it is intended to avoid conflicts between jquery and any other javascript libraries that may be using the $ reference.  if there are no other libraries or potential conflicts you can drop that entirely.

you have multiple document ready calls you only need one and you can put all of your remaining handlers within that one

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // everything goes here you only need one document ready
    $('.image_one').removeClass('active');

    $(".image_one").click(function () {
       alert("Jquery is Working");
    });

});
```

Comment: You should note he is currently using a different class. It just has a longer name than `active` it is `image_one_active` he isn't actually modifying the class name he is adding and removing the `image_one_active` class.

Comment: first line of my answer was - "i would go about this problem in a slightly different fashion" but this conversation is irrelevant, sorry for off topic

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to do it. I added 1 event listener on document and 1 on each anchor.

Here's my code:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).on('click', function() {
        $(this)
            .find('img.image_one_active')
            .removeClass('image_one_active')
            .addClass('image_one');
        $(this)
            .find('img.image_two_active')
            .removeClass('image_two_active')
            .addClass('image_two');
    });

    $('img').eq(0).on('click', function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this)
            .removeClass('image_one')
            .addClass('image_one_active')
            .siblings('img')
            .removeClass('image_two_active')
            .addClass('image_two');
    });

    $('img').eq(1).on('click', function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(this)
            .removeClass('image_two')
            .addClass('image_two_active')
            .siblings('img')
            .removeClass('image_one_active')
            .addClass('image_one');
    });
})(jQuery);
```

I changed `a` to `img` just to see if its working.

### **EDIT**

Code can be shortened if you change CSS to increase specificity of `image_one_active` and `image_two_active`

**CSS**

```
.sprite {
  background-image: url('http://goo.gl/OKPx8');
  width: 200px; height: 200px;
}
.image_one { background-position: -25px -85px; }
.image_two { background-position: -25px -105px; }
img.image_one_active { background-position: -25px -35px; }
img.image_two_active { background-position: -25px -55px; }
```

**JS**

```
(function($) {
    var imgOne = $('img.image_one'),
        imgTwo = $('img.image_two');

    $(document).on('click', function() {
        imgOne.removeClass('image_one_active');
        imgTwo.removeClass('image_two_active');
    });

    imgOne.on('click', function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        imgOne.addClass('image_one_active');
        imgTwo.removeClass('image_two_active');
    });

    imgTwo.on('click', function() {
        event.stopPropagation();
        imgTwo.addClass('image_two_active')
        imgOne.removeClass('image_one_active');
    });
```

[**+Specificity**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity)

Comment: Basically you did what I did except rather than spell things out to help the OP understand you chained it all together? Also rather than using `.eq(n)` you would be better checking for the actual image using `$('img').on('click', 'image_one', function() {`

Comment: I didn't copy and edit your answer. But I agree, `eq()` is not a good idea. I edited my answer and cached the two images

Comment: Better but you are still assigning the event handler to `$('img').eq(0).on(...` this should be `imgOne.on(...` now.

Comment: Forgot about that. I changed it now. I tried to approve your edit but it said, "Edit already approved/rejected", Weird ... But I was wondering, Adding, say n, click events on `document` or on different individual elements, will there be any performance difference?

Comment: An advantage of using `$(document).on('click', 'element'...` over `$('element').on('click'...` is that if you ever add additional elements to the document that did not exist when the event handler was added will also have the event applied to them where as using the 2nd method of `$('element').on('click'...` will only add the handler to the elements that currently exist.

Comment: ok! I understand now. I changed the code to do same thing for n `img` elements at same level. Can this code be changed to have all event listeners attached to document? http://jsfiddle.net/bgxF9/
Thanks for help Lavabeams :)

Comment: Yeah for example http://jsfiddle.net/bgxF9/2/ now the images are appended and not actually part of the document when the handler is added and the event handler will still be called. I do like how you used the sprite logo because of the class called sprite. Made me laugh :)

Comment: I thought that it would be the most appropriate image here :P ... This might sound stupid but `images` var is not declared but code is still working. How?

Comment: Moved discussion to chat - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30526/discussion-between-lavabeams-and-sourabh